# Did The Sahaba Prayed To The Prophet instead of Allah?

Tags: hadith, sharia, shirk, ilm-ar-rijal, tawassul

An Islamophobic website cites the following narration to prove that the Sahaba prayed to the Prophet instead of Allah. They attack Islam in such a way. The following are some of the narrations they have quoted:-

It is just as necessary to have esteem and respect for the Prophet after his death as it were when he was alive. This means to show it whenever the Prophet, his hadith or sunna are mentioned, when anyone hears his name or anything about his life or how his family and relatives behaved. It includes respect for the People of his House (ah al-bayt) and his Companions…

Abu Humayd said, "Abu Ja'far, the Amir al-Mu'minin, had a dispute with Malik in the Prophet's mosque. Malik said to him, 'Amir al-Mu'minin, do not raise your voice in this mosque. Allah taught the people how to behave by saying, ‘Do not raise your voices above the Prophet’ (49:2) He praises people with the words, "Those who lower their voices in the presence of the Messenger of Allah." (49:3) He censures people, saying, "Those who call you..." Respect for him when he is dead is the same as respect for him when he was alive."

"Abu Ja'far was humbled by this. He asked Malik, 'Abu Abdullah, **do you face qibla when you supplicate or do you face the Messenger of Allah?**' He replied, '**Why would you turn your face from him when he is YOUR MEANS and the means of your father, Adam, to Allah on the Day of Rising?** **I face him and ASK HIM to intercede and Allah will grant his intercession. Allah says, "If, when you wronged yourselves, they had come to you.**"'" (4:64) (Pp. 237-238)

al-Darimi in the Chapter 15 of the Muqaddima (Introduction) to his Sunan (1:43) entitled: "Allah's generosity to His Prophet after his death," relates from Aws ibn `Abd Allah with a good chain: "The people of Madina complained to` A'isha of the severe drought that they were suffering. She said: "Go to the Prophet's grave and open a window towards the sky so that there will be no roof between him and the sky." They did so, after which they were watered with such rain that vegetation grew and the camels got fat. That year was named the Year of Plenty." (Encyclopedia of Islamic Doctrine, III. QUESTIONS ON TAWASSUL)

They are also claiming that Hadith narrator "Sa`id ibn Zayd Abu al-Hasan" is a thiqa narrator and Albani's declaration of him being weak has been rejected by the scholars!

They cite the following website to prove their point that why Albani was wrong when he classified it as weak:-

**http://www.sunnah.org/publication/encyclopedia/html/tawassul.htm**

They also claim that Allah created Adam (Alayhisalam) because of Prophet (Sallallahualayhiwassalam)!

Al-Bayhaqi cited the following hadith in his book "Dala'il an-Nubuwwah" (Signs of Prophethood): Narrated 'Umar Ibn al-Khattab: the Prophet said: "When Adam committed the sin, he said to Allah, **'O My Lord, I ask You with reference to Muhammad to forgive me'**. Allah said: 'O Adam! How did you know about Muhammad, for I have not yet created him?' Adam replied, 'O My Lord, when You created me, I looked up and saw inscribed on the legs of the Throne the words: There is no God worthy of worship except Allah and Muhammad is His Messenger. I knew that you do not attach to Your name but the name of the dearest of Your Creation.' Allah said to Adam, 'You have spoken rightly, Adam. **Muhammad is the dearest of My Creation. I have forgiven you because you asked by Muhammad. AND HAD IT NOT BEEN FOR HIM, I WOULD NOT HAVE CREATED YOU.**'" This hadith was narrated by al-Hakim who also classified it as sahih (authentic). Among the transmitters of this hadith is 'Abd ar-Rahman Ibn Zayd Ibn Aslam. Al-Haythami said: "This hadith was reported by at-Dabarani and in its chain of transmitters are people I do not know. Al-Hakim was therefore mistaken in classifying this hadith as sahih because he himself criticised 'Abd ar-rahman Ibn Zayd Ibn Aslam in his book ad-Du'afa, so how can he state the authenticity of the hadith after he had criticised him?!!" (Tafsir Ibn Kathir, Part 1, Surah Al-Fatiah Surah Al-Baqarah, ayat 1 to 141, Abridged by Sheikh Nasib Ar-Rafa'i [Al-Firdous Ltd., London: Second Edition 1998], p. 107, fn 10; underline and capital emphasis ours)

They also said that a man came to the grave of Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) and prayed for rain!

It is also narrated that Ibn ‘Umar would place his hand on the seat of the Prophet’s minbar then wipe his face with it2 and that Abu Ayyub was seen resting his face on the Prophet’s grave.3 This practice of the Companions clarifies two matters. The first is the permissibility of asking Allah for things by the Prophet (tawassul) after his death since by their act the Companions were truly making tawassul. Likewise it is permissible to ask Allah for things by means of other pious Muslims. The second is the permissibility of tabarruk or seeking blessing (baraka) from objects connected to the Prophet.

It is similarly related that in the year of the drought called al-Ramada (17-18) during the successorship of ‘Umar the Companion Bilal ibn al-Harith, while slaughtering a sheep for his kin, noticed that the sheep’s bones had turned red because the drying flesh was clinging to them. He cried out “Ya Muhammadah!" Then he saw the Prophet in a dream ordering him to go to ‘Umar with the tidings of coming rain on condition that ‘Umar show wisdom. Hearing this, ‘Umar assembled the people and came out to pray for rain with al-‘Abbas, the uncle of the Prophet.4 The same is related from the Companion or Successor Malik ibn ‘Iyad, also known as Malik al-Dar:5 **A man came to the grave of the Prophet and said: “Messenger of Allah, ask for rain for your Community (istasqi li’ummatik), for verily they have but perished!"** after which the Prophet appeared to him in a dream telling him: "Go to ‘Umar and give him my greeting, then tell him that they will be watered. Tell him: Be clever!" The man went and told ‘Umar. The latter wept and said: "My Lord! I spare no effort except in what escapes my power!"6 Ibn Hajar identifies Malik al-Dar as ‘Umar’s treasurer and the man who visited and saw the Prophet in his dream as the Companion Bilal ibn al-Harith, counting this hadith among the reasons for al-Bukhari’s naming of the chapter “The people’s request to their leader for rain if they suffer drought."

What is the reality of these reports?

Comment: Please format your post properly, and clearly mark quotes and other text, and elaborate what your actual issue is, people will always attack Islam. If you want to ask about a specific narrator or narration then ask it in a separate focused question.

Comment: @UmH -Thanks I will properly post my question next time. I was actually concerned about two narrations 1) The narration of Aisha (Radhiyallahu'anah) where she said to the people to go to the tomb of Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam). 2) The narration which says that Allah created Adam (Alayhisalam) because of Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam). Please throw some light on it.

Comment: Are you asking about their authenticity? In brief, the authenticity of both is disputed, as there are narrators which some have criticized and others have accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The narrations you have quoted are not about praying **to** the Prophet instead of Allah, rather they are clearly praying **to Allah** and using the Messenger of Allah ﷺ as a wasilah.

- They ask Allah to accept their supplication  for the sake of the Prophet
- They ask Allah to accept their supplication for the sake of their belief in and regard for the Prophet
- They ask the Prophet to supplicate for them to Allah.

The validity of this is established through the Quran:

> #### ولو أنهم إذ ظلموا أنفسهم جاءوك فاستغفروا الله واستغفر لهم الرسول لوجدوا الله توابا رحيما
>
> And if, when they wronged themselves, they had come to you, [O Muhammad], and asked forgiveness of Allah and the Messenger had asked forgiveness for them, they would have found Allah Accepting of repentance and Merciful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:64](http://quran.com/4/64)</sup>

And Sunnah:

> #### أن رجلا ضرير البصر أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال: ادع الله أن يعافيني قال: إن شئت دعوت، وإن شئت صبرت فهو خير لك. قال: فادعه، قال: فأمره أن يتوضأ فيحسن وضوءه ويدعو بهذا الدعاء: اللهم إني أسألك وأتوجه إليك بنبيك محمد نبي الرحمة، إني توجهت بك إلى ربي في حاجتي هذه لتقضى لي، اللهم فشفعه في
>
> A blind man came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said: “Supplicate to Allah to heal me.”
>
> He (ﷺ) said: “If you wish I will supplicate for you, and if you wish, you can be patient, for that is better for you.” He said: “Then supplicate to Him.”
>
> He said: “So he ordered him to perform Wudu’ and to make his Wudu’ complete, and to supplicate with this supplication:
>
> 'O Allah, I ask You and turn towards You by Your Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ), the Prophet of Mercy. Indeed, I have turned to my Lord, by means of You, concerning this need of mine, so that it can be resolved, so O Allah so accept his intercession for me'
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/209)</sup>

> #### أن عمر بن الخطاب رضي الله عنه، كان إذا قحطوا استسقى بالعباس بن عبد المطلب، فقال: اللهم إنا كنا نتوسل إليك بنبينا فتسقينا، وإنا نتوسل إليك بعم نبينا فاسقنا، قال: فيسقون
>
> Whenever drought threatened them, Umar bin Al-Khattab, used to ask Al-Abbas bin Abdul Muttalib to invoke Allah for rain.
>
> He used to say, "O Allah! We used to ask our Prophet to invoke You for rain, and You would bless us with rain, and now we ask his uncle to invoke You for rain. O Allah ! Bless us with rain."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/15/5)</sup>

Note that there are various means of tawassul, among them some are agreed upon and regarding some there is difference of opinion.

With regard to tawassul using the Messenger of Allah. It is permitted by consensus when it is supplicating to Allah for the sake of one's belief in, obedience towards and love for the Prophet as it is a form of tawassul with good deeds, see the relevant [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/132).

Regarding asking the Prophet to make Dua on our behalf, there are three cases for it:

- During his life. This is agreed upon.
- For the afterlife. This is agreed upon, see relevant [hadith](https://sunnah.com/urn/43910).
- During his death. There is difference of opinion on it.

Answer (score -1):

The link below is informative :

http://www.salafiri.com/?s=Tawassul

Also I recommend reading Sheikh al-Abani's book on this matter :

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://o.b5z.net/i/u/6103974/f/tawassul_in_english.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwitu9nOnbHqAhX463MBHdfZDtQQFjAIegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw37JCjEIYOUXm2LPDnzGeYH